# yii many-to-many CDbCriteria with type column in bridge table

Tags: yii

```
Table AgentType:
agent_type_id
agent_type_name

Table Agent:
agent_id
agent_name

Table Talent:
talent_id
talent_name

Table TalentAgent:
talent_id
agent_id
agent_type_id

Table AgentType
agent_id
agent_type_id
```

Talent Model Relations:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
       'talent_agent' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TalentAgent', 'talent_id'),
       'agent' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Agent', 'agent_id', 'through' => 'talent_agent'),
       'agents' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Agent', 'nca_talent_agent(talent_id,agent_id)'),
    );
}
```

Agent Model Relations:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'talent_agent' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TalentAgent', 'agent_id'),
        'talent' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Talent', 'talent_id', 'through' => 'talent_agent'),
        'agent_type' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'AgentType', 'nca_agent_agent_type(agent_id,agent_type_id)'),
    );
}
```

AgentType Relations:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'talent' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Talent', 'nca_talent_agent(talent_id,agent_id,agent_type_id)'),
        'agent' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Agent', 'nca_agent_agent_type(agent_id,agent_type_id)'),
    );
}
```

TalentAgent Relations:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'talent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Talent', 'talent_id'),
        'agent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Agent', 'agent_id'),
        'agent_type' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'AgentType', 'agent_type_id'),
    );
}
```

In my grid view I have the 3 different agent types listed for each talent:

```
array(
    'name'=>'agent_primary',
    'value'=>'$data->getPrimaryAgent($data->talent_id, false)',
    'filter'=>CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'agent_primary', CHtml::listData(Agent::model()->with('agent_type')->findAll(array('condition'=>'agent_type.agent_type_id = 1')),'agent_id', 'name')),
),
array(
    'name'=>'agent_voice',
    'value'=>'$data->getVoiceAgent($data->talent_id, false)',
    'filter'=>CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'agent_voice', CHtml::listData(Agent::model()->with('agent_type')->findAll(array('condition'=>'agent_type.agent_type_id = 2')),'agent_id', 'name')),
),
array(
    'name'=>'agent_commercial',
    'value'=>'$data->getCommercialAgent($data->talent_id, false)',
    'filter'=>CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'agent_commercial', CHtml::listData(Agent::model()->with('agent_type')->findAll(array('condition'=>'agent_type.agent_type_id = 3')),'agent_id', 'name')),
),
```

In my search filter for the grid-view I'm trying to be able to filter by each different agent type independently, but I'm not sure where to add the agent type filter, here is what I have so far:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array('agent');
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->compare('agent.agent_id',$this->agent_primary);
```

How can I filter by agent_type_id? Thanks!

Comment: Join with the `AgentType` table? You can join multiple tables, not just one.

Comment: you mean `$criteria->with = array('agent_type');` ?

Comment: Yes, and if you have to, you can join with both `agent` and `agent_type`, like so: `$criteria->with = array('agent','agent_type')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hopes of helping others that come across this issue here is what I did in the end:

Criteria:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array('agent','agent.agent_type');
$criteria->together = true;
```

Then you can apply your compare criteria (yes I hard-coded the type_id for now):

```
$criteria->compare("agent_type.agent_type_id",array(3));
$criteria->compare('agent.agent_id', $this->primary_agent_id);
```